# Correc sequence of typing

Tags: java

I would like to know is ther any programmaticly way createing JFrame I mean which is correct

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(250,200);
      or

JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
            frame.setSize(250,200);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);

      or
JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
            frame.setSize(250,200);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

now this codes work ok with simple programm but what about if I use threads in bigger programmes

Comment: There is not such things call order here. Order is not important here

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not here.

Comment: `pack` and `setSize` both change the size of the window. The end result depends on which call is last. If you call `setVisible` before setting the size of the window the window will appear with the wrong size briefly.

Answer (score 2):

- There is no need of calling `setSize()` method if you are using proper layout manger and calling `pack()`.  If you really need absolute size then override [JComponent#getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) method of `JPanel`.

  Read more [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)
- Call `setVisible()` method in the end after adding all the component. Don't directly add components in top level container. Use other container such as `JPanel` then finally add it in `JFrame`.
- The order of calling `setDefaultCloseOperation()` method doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In this case call order is not important, but as a general rule, i would place pack at the end as call of pack is some cases should be last called ( after adding all components to your GUI )